# What would you say links Differential Geometry & Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

What would you say links differential geometry and linear algebra? how and why?

Comment: Well, for one thing, the tangent space at a point, cotangent space, spaces of $k$-forms etc. are all real vector spaces.  Not to mention de Rham cohomology.

Comment: When you refer to differential geometry, are you talking about curvature and surfaces or are you talking about the study of $n$-dimensional manifolds and vector fields?

Comment: curvature and surfaces

Answer (score 4):

As Daniel Schepler said the tangent space to a manifold at a point is a real vector space. The differential of a smooth map between manifolds is a linear map between the tangent spaces.

An important idea is "linearization"- that is you can learn a lot on the behaviour of a mapping through its differential (e.g the inverse function theorem).

It is worth noting that while linear algebra is extremely important for differential geometry, some of its stuff are less useful than others.

The theory of diagonalization of linear operators, which forms a large part of the material studied in linear algebra courses is less relevant in general (since it is on operators $V \to V$ while the differential of a map is a linear map between two *different* vector spaces).

(However, when studying fixed points of diffeomorphisms, the more "familiar" setting of maps $V \to V$ returns).

Most of the relevant linear algebra (besides the truly elementary ones), is related to alternating maps, exterior algebra and symmetric tensors etc, which are usually not studied in first year algebra courses.

Comment: Just a small comment: That symmetric matrices are diagonalizable (and have real eigenvalues) is needed to define "principal curvatures" for (say) surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Later on, diagonalization of the Hodge star is central to the Riemannian geometry of 4-manifolds.  Separately: I'm not sure if the OP has studied abstract manifolds and tangent spaces.

Comment: Thanks. I agree about the relevance of diagonalization of symmetric matrices to principal curvatures, this is a nice observation! Can you elaborate on how the diagonalization of the Hodge star is relevant to the  geometry of 4-manifolds? (I don't know much about geometry of $4$-manifolds, and this sounds interesting. I am also not sure what exactly do you mean by "diagonalizing" the Hodge star, I guess you refer to $\star_2:\Lambda_2(T^*M) \to \Lambda_2(T^*M)$.)

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to decomposing $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^4)$ into the eigenspaces of the Hodge star operator $\ast \colon \Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^4) \to \Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^4)$.  In dimensions $n \geq 5$, the decomposition of the Riemann curvature tensor as $\text{Scal} \oplus \text{Ric} \oplus \text{Weyl}$ is $\text{SO}(n)$-irreducible.  However, in dimension $n = 4$, the Weyl piece splits further.  This splitting of the Weyl tensor has to do with the eigenspaces of the Hodge star operator on $2$-forms.